# Not enough tokens when sending SOL to other wallet on Main net

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, spl-token, phantom

I am trying to send `1000000000 * 0.00001` lamports to my other wallet. Sol fee is like `0.00011` SOL in total it's like `0.00001+0.00011=0.00012`. I have `0.04444` SOL in my wallet already but when I hit the send button Phantom Wallet says that there are not enough tokens I have in my wallet.
Where I am doing wrong? I am using the below code for doing transaction.

```
 transactionInstructions.push(
          createTransferInstruction(
            fromAccount.address, // source
            associatedTokenTo, // dest
            publicKey,
            1000000000 * 0.00001
          )
        );
```

I am using mainnet.helius-rpc.com.

[image]